# invalid literal for int() with base 10: \xef\xbb\xbf10

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a number from file and convert it to int in order to compare it to a value, but I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for `int()` with base 10: `\xef\xbb\xbf10`

I do something like this:

```
def check_id(str_id)
    csvfile = file('strings.csv')
    for csvline in csvfile:
        parts = csvline.split('|')
        if int(parts[0]) == str_id:
            print "id found"
```

The file inside is like a table (it's a CSV file) and inside, it looks like this:

```
10|item 10|description|information|price
```

This is one line of the file; there are more lines with several IDs, so I want to see if an ID exists in file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you encounter at some point is the [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), $EF $BB $BF.

You are trying to be smarter than Python. Python has a [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) that will do the CSV parsing properly; use it instead of tinkering your own half-baked parser.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem, it seems like encoding problem.
opening the csv file with csv module and reading first column still gave me same error.

Comment: The remove the BOM yourself before feeding the data into the csv parser

Comment: I have removed the the BOM over Notepad 'Code' menu then it worked.